# How to use Cookies to count visits in PHP?

Tags: php, html, cookies, session-cookies

I am new to PHP and I am having quite the trouble with using Cookies!
So I am trying to have one cookie that will keep count of the number of times the page has been loaded within a lifetime of 1 minute. Once it has reached its lifetime it needs to be unset and the counter should go back to 0.

So far here is what I have:
At the top of the Php file

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user_start'] = time();
  $cookie_name = "counter";
  $cookie_value = 0;
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); 
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (time() - $_SESSION['user_start'] < 60) {
  $counter = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] +1; 
  setcookie($cookie_name, $counter);
  echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
else{
  unset($_SESSION['user_start']);
  unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I suspect what you're attempting here isn't going to be anything like what you actually want...

Comment: I'm trying to have a page counter. So when everytime you load the page, it will increment the counter. The counter only last for 1 minute and then goes back to 0.

Comment: Cookies exist on the user's machine though, so each user would have their own cookie... you're not going to have an aggregate counter with this, each user will just see the number of times they've refreshed the page while that cookie is live ... is that really what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that correctly, so you mean I should do $_COOKIE["counter"] = $cookie_name ?

Comment: @CD001 Yes exactly!

Comment: Nevermind. When you do `$counter = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] +1;` ... it will throw an index undefined notice, because the very first time a user hits the page, `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]` will not exist, since it didnt exist coming into the page. There are other issues in your code example too.

Comment: @IncredibleHat OH Okay! Then I need to declare $_Cookie[$cookie_name] = 0; in the header correct? Because I do have a counter that is printing out but it never restarts after 1 minute

Comment: You can do something like `$counter = isset($_COOKIE['counter']) ? ++$_COOKIE['counter'] : 0; setcookie("counter", $counter, time()+60);` ... but the problem will be that you'll be resetting the expiry time each time you rewrite the cookie.

Answer (score -1):

It's a little odd - but this should do the trick, I'm storing both the *counter* value and the *expiry* time in a cookie in JSON format. That way you can just increment the counter whilst keeping the initial expiry time (e.g. 1 minute after the initial request).

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$expires = time()+60;

if(isset($_COOKIE['counter'])) {    
    $data = json_decode($_COOKIE['counter']);
    $counter = ++$data->counter;
    $expires = $data->expires;
}

$jsonData = json_encode(['counter' => $counter, 'expires' => $expires]);
setcookie("counter", $jsonData, $expires);

echo $counter;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I put this in the header or after the <body> tag? just to be sure :o

Comment: @dancingRageForFUn You put this before you output anything to the user at all. If you've started pushing your output already, `setcookie` will throw an error.